# pvscan --activate: `Command does not accept option: --activate ay.`

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm trying to work out how to use `pvscan --activate`.

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pvscan.8.html) says:

> ```
>    -a|--activate y|n|ay
>           Auto-activate LVs in a VG when the PVs scanned have completed
>           the VG.  (Only ay is applicable.)
> ```

I've tried:

```
# pvscan --activate y                   
  Command does not accept option: --activate y.
# pvscan --activate n
  Command does not accept option: --activate n.
# pvscan --activate ay
  Command does not accept option: --activate ay.
# pvscan --activate
pvscan: option '--activate' requires an argument
  Error during parsing of command line.
```

I'm running:

```
# pvscan --version
  LVM version:     2.02.173(2) (2017-07-20)
  Library version: 1.02.142 (2017-07-20)
  Driver version:  4.35.0
  Configuration:   ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --sbindir=/usr/bin --with-udev-prefix=/usr --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/usr/lib/systemd/system --with-default-pid-dir=/run --with-default-dm-run-dir=/run --with-default-run-dir=/run/lvm --enable-pkgconfig --enable-readline --enable-dmeventd --enable-cmdlib --enable-applib --enable-udev_sync --enable-udev_rules --with-default-locking-dir=/run/lock/lvm --enable-lvmetad --with-thin=internal --with-cache=internal --enable-udev-systemd-background-jobs
```

How do I invoke `pvscan --activate`?

Comment: The man page says it only works with `--cache`?

Comment: Ah, it does work with combined with `--cache`. From my reading of the section `Automatic activation` it seems to imply the second step can be done independently of the first. It still seems dodgy to me documenting `-a n` which can't be used in *any* situation. Make an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Usage suggestion of the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pvscan.8.html) suggests `--activate` is only valid with `--cache`

```
pvscan --cache
       [ -b|--background ]
       [ -a|--activate ay ]
       [ -j|--major Number ]
       [    --minor Number ]
       [ COMMON_OPTIONS ]
       [ String|PV ... ]
```